# Android: How to disable Desktops?

Tags: android, settings

We have an App for a tablet with Android 2.2. This is the only App that should run on this tablet. It starts automatically.
Thats why the user should not have access to other Apps on this tablet, especially not to the settings.
How we can realize this?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably write your application as a Home application. There is an example in the developer docs here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html

Then you'd be able to switch the default Home application for your one.